# Can't find TOCBLOCK

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So I'm using dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu each on SSD).
Since the last time I updated Ubuntu, I can't boot into it again. I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdZjN.jpg) and don't boot into Ubuntu.

I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889912/dual-boot-ubuntu-doesnt-boot-with-error-cannot-find-tocblock-database-maybe-c) but didn't solve the problem. **When I put # before the UUIDs I get more errors**.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: 20.04LTS with Linux 5.9.10-050910-generic

Comment: If you use an official kernel is it different?

Comment: I mean I installed Ubuntu from the Ubuntu website few months ago, and last week I got an update, I installed it and since then I can't boot

Answer (score 2):

The error message "Cannot find PRIVHEAD structure. LDM database is corrupt. Aborting.") is issued by the kernel when it attempts to parse the Windows Logical Disk Manager TOCBLOCK (table of contents structure).  The 64 bit magic in the header (value 0x5052495648454144) does not match, so the ldm driver fails to validate the LDM data and gives up.

Comment: Ah ok I understand the issue now, any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

D'oh. Commented to someone else's ancient post by mistake. So, trying again...

Make a bootable USB key with the same or newer version of Ubuntu on it. You can do this under Windows.

Boot from it and check your Ubuntu partitions for errors.

Try booting off the Ubuntu installation again, and if it works, do a full system update immediately then reboot. The quickest way is to type the following commands:

```
sudo -s
apt update
apt full-upgrade -y
apt autoremove -y
apt clean
apt purge
```

Then reboot.

The last 3 commands clean up after the update. This is an often-neglected step.

If checking the disk using a key doesn't help, I suggest reinstalling over the top. This should keep your files and settings so long as you do not reformat the disk.