# Initramfs unpacking faild: Decoding faild dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I'm using dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu each on SSD). Since the last time I updated Ubuntu, I can't boot into it again. I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdZjN.jpg) and don't boot into Ubuntu.

I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889912/dual-boot-ubuntu-doesnt-boot-with-error-cannot-find-tocblock-database-maybe-c) but didn't solve the problem. When I put # before the UUIDs I get more errors

I also tried `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` but nothing changed.

How can I boot to my system again?
Ubuntu 20.04 with Linux 5.9.10-050910-generic

Comment: Is the 5.9 kernel even out for general use yet?

Comment: I have it !! I also have older versions but not working